# Unit for fit_time and score_time in sklearn cross_validate

Tags: python, scikit-learn

in the [sklearn's documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html) they state:

> fit_time `The time for fitting the estimator on the train set for each cv split.`
>
> score_time `The time for scoring the estimator on the test set for each cv split. (Note time for scoring on the train set is not included even if return_train_score is set to True`

Ok, but does anyone actually know the **units** of these answers? My best guess is that they are in seconds by the execution time of my cross validations, but I am still unsure.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [this comment in the source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/55a65a2fa5653257225d7e184da3d0c00ff852b1/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L673), I would assume they are in seconds.

> ```
> fit_time : float
>   Time spent for fitting in seconds.
> ```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).